# Encountering errors during Apache Cassandra startup

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04

I encounter various and unknown (syntax) errors when trying to start a newly installed Apache Cassandra in version 1.1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

What I did so far:

**Installing:**

```
$ wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/1.1.7/apache-cassandra-1.1.7-bin.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf apache-cassandra-1.1.7-bin.tar.gz -C /opt
$ ln -s /opt/apache-cassandra-1.1.7 /opt/cassandra
$ chown cassandra -R /opt/apache-cassandra-1.1.7
$ chown cassandra -R /opt/cassandra
```

**Trying to start:**

```
$ sudo /opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra as cassandra
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 54: [: Illegal number: 
/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 58: [: Illegal number: 
/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 62: [: Illegal number: 
expr: syntax error
/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 76: [: Illegal number: 
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/opt/cassandra/bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -XmsM -XmxM -XmnM -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
$ Invalid initial heap size: -XmsM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

**The installed Java version:**

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I cannot find any Cassandra logs. Did anyone also encounter these errors? How can I get Cassandra to start up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.1.7 is incredibly old. Why are you using that?

Comment: The project I'm working seems to require this. Can I substitude the 1.1.7 with a newer version without experiencing any side effects?

Comment: If you have existing data you'll need to follow the upgrade guides. The oldest supported version is 2.2.8 I think.

Comment: So if 1.1.7 is an older version, these 'illegal number' errors might be caused by incompatible Java code?

Comment: No, 1.1.7 is so old I can't be bothered to go work out why the run scripts have gone wrong.

Comment: I suspect that the scripts were written for bash and Ubuntu by default uses dash. You could try changing the #!/bin/sh at the head of bin/cassandra to #!/bin/bash or you could change the symlink in /bin for sh to use bash instead.